# Controller Extension Test Help?

Tags: controller, code-coverage, failing-tests, extension

I will start out by apologizing for being a total n00b but, I need some help increasing my code coverage ASAP. Currently I am at 73%... so close!!
Any help/advice/anything is a huge help! Thank You!
Here is my Controller Extension code

```
public class GroupSignUpSAVEEXT {
    private final Contact con;
    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.
    public GroupSignUpSAVEExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.con = (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    public static String firstName {
        get { return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('FirstName'); }
    set; 
    }
    public static String lastName {
        get { return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('LastName'); }
    set; 
    }
    public static String theEmail {
        get { return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Email'); }
    set; 
    }
   public String strSaveResult {
        get;
        set;
    }  
}
```

And here is my Test Code

```
    @isTest
public class GroupSignUpEXT_TEST {

    static testmethod void testMyConstructor() 
    {
        Contact a = new Contact(); 
        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
        GroupSignUpSAVEEXT extension = new GroupSignUpSAVEEXT(controller); 

       Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name='Test Account' ;
        insert testAccount; 

      Contact con= new contact();
     con.Email = 'Test@gmail.com';
     con.LastName= 'TodayTest';
     con.FirstName= 'Test';
     insert con;   

   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('qp', 'yyyy');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow writing test method like this:

```
//create Account
Account acct = new Account(Name='test', RecordTypeId=redTypeId,......);
insert acct;

//Create Contact
Contact con= new contact();
con.Email = 'Test@gmail.com';
con.LastName= 'TodayTest';
con.FirstName= 'Test';
con.AccountId = acct.Id;
insert con;   

//create pageReference
PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
Test.setCurrentPage(page);

//pass parameter to the page
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',con.Id);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('FirstName',con.FirstName);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('LastName',con.LastName);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Email',con.Email);


//create an instance of controller.
ApexPages.StandardController standrdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(con);  

GroupSignUpSAVEEXT clsInstance = new GroupSignUpSAVEEXT(standrdcontroller);
System.assertEquals(.....);

String strFirstName = GroupSignUpSAVEEXT.firstName;
System.assertEquals(.....);

String strLastName = GroupSignUpSAVEEXT.lastName;
System.assertEquals(.....);

String strtheEmail = GroupSignUpSAVEEXT.theEmail;
System.assertEquals(.....);
```

Refer [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) for properly writing test classes, as in your code block there are no asserts.

Test classes are meant for testing unit test case scenario, and **not meant for 75% coverage for deployment.**

Comment: I cannot get the //create an instance of controller section to work. Where does the "mpr_copy" come from?

Comment: small typo mistake, updated the code